# how to adjust javascript regexpression

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I need to adjust a regex I am using for a file name. currently the file is structured 02-2015 VRF WE32.pdf
the regex splits up the string into 3 pieces by the spaces. This works fine. the result is

```
02-2015
VRF
WE32
```

But now i need to split the string into 4 pieces. the 4th being the digits in the 'WE32'. so it needs to look like this

```
02-2015
VRF
WE
32
```

Here is what I am using, including some screenshots

```
var matchesPip = file.name.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*(\S*\s*)(\S*)/i);
var matchesLoc = file.name.match(/^\d+\D\d+\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)\./i);
var matchesLocCode = file.name.match(NEED HELP HERE);
    $scope.pip = $scope.pipeLookup[matchesPip[1]];
    $scope.loc = $scope.locationLookup[matchesLoc[2]];
    $scope.locCode = $scope.locationCodeLookup[matchesLocCode[3]];
```

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to provide number matching group `(\d+)` after non-spaces one:

```
^(\d+\D\d+)\s*?(\S*)\s*(\S*?)(\d+)\.
```

**Test:** https://regex101.com/r/bP7oF2/1

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use split instead ? For example

```
var fn = '02-2015 VRF WE32.pdf';
var chunks = fn.split(' ');
var moreChunks = chunks[2].split('.');
alert (moreChunks[0]);
```

will give you WE32